# What causes pgAdmin4 to close when disabling join methods or creating indexes?

Tags: sql, postgresql, crash, pgadmin-4

So i have a query which i ran and gives the results that i want. It is then asked of me to disable some of the join methods in order to get the execution time average of the query using explain analyse. At some point though when i run the code in which i disable a certain join method it crashes/closes the pgAdmin4 application. Not all the time though, some points i could go with running 4 to 5 set enable of the join methods but on other occasions i could run 1 or 2 set enables. This same exact problem also occurs when creating indexes in tables.

I haven't tried anything other than running it on another laptop which encountered the same problem.
Here is the code which i run:

```
SET max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0;

SELECT relname,relkind,reltuples,relpages
FROM pg_class
WHERE relname LIKE 'Person%';

VACUUM ANALYSE;

    EXPLAIN ANALYSE WITH program_students AS(
                SELECT s.amka,j."ProgramID",s.entry_date
                FROM "Student" s,"Joins" j
                WHERE s.amka=j."StudentAMKA"
            ),
            year5_students AS(
                SELECT ps.amka,ps."ProgramID",ps.entry_date
                FROM program_students ps,"Program" p
                WHERE ps."ProgramID"=p."ProgramID" AND p."Duration"=5
            ),
            year5_persons AS(
                SELECT ys.amka,ys."ProgramID",ys.entry_date,p.city_id
                FROM year5_students ys,"Person" p
                WHERE ys.amka=p.amka
            ),
            year5_persons_atleast2 AS(
                SELECT yp.amka,yp.city_id,yp.entry_date,COUNT(DISTINCT yp."ProgramID") AS progrcount
                FROM year5_persons yp
                GROUP BY yp.amka,yp.city_id,yp.entry_date
                HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT yp."ProgramID")>=2
            )
                SELECT c.name,COUNT(DISTINCT yp.amka) AS student_count
                FROM "Cities" c
                LEFT JOIN year5_persons_atleast2 yp ON c.id=yp.city_id
                WHERE yp.entry_date>='2000-09-01' AND yp.entry_date<='2021-09-30' OR yp.entry_date IS NULL
                GROUP BY c.name
                ORDER BY student_count DESC;

--NOTE BETWEEN EACH SET OR CREATION OF INDEX OR DROP I USE EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SET enable_hashjoin=off;            
SET enable_mergejoin=off;       
SET enable_nestloop=off;        
SET enable_mergejoin=on;
SET enable_nestloop=on;         
SET enable_hashjoin=on;         
CREATE INDEX Student_entry_index ON "Student" USING btree(entry_date);          
CREATE INDEX Program_id_index ON "Program" USING hash("ProgramID");
CREATE INDEX Program_duration_index ON "Program" USING hash("Duration");
```

Furthermore the code is supposed to print out all the cities in the database which have a population >= 50000 and how many students from each city have participated in at least 2 programs of duration = 5 years and their induction is between a certain date of our choice. (All the cities should be printed out even if they have no students participating).

Is there anything i can do to fix the application from closing?

Comment: To me a hard crash means you need to reformat (or buy a new) the disk and either reinstall everything, or restore from a back up.  Is that what you mean?  Maybe you should specify more clearly what is happening.

Comment: Yes i am sorry. Not a hard crash, the application just closes. I run for example SET enable_hashjoin=off; it runs/returns that the set was succesfull and then immediately after the pgadmin4 app just closes

Comment: pgAdmin4 is just a client, use a different one and you don't have this problem. psql is just one of many options you have: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients

Comment: Okay thank you very much i will try another client

Comment: The server log file should have done kind of info for you. It might give you complete answer, or maybe just a small clue.

Comment: if i may ask where can i find the server log file?